# A step in the derivation of the Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stochastic-calculus

In the usual derivation of the Fokker-Planck, e.g. [here](https://sites.me.ucsb.edu/%7Emoehlis/moehlis_papers/appendix.pdf), we start with a generic continuous-time process $X_t$ and look at the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(Y) \frac{\partial P(Y,t|X)}{\partial t}dY$.

In equation (9), the Taylor expansion of $h(Y)$ for $Y\approx Z$ brings about the term
$$ D^{(n)}(Z) = \frac{1}{n!} \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\Delta t} \int_{-\infty}^\infty (Y-Z)^n P(Y,\Delta t|Z) dY.$$

To derive the Fokker-Planck, we assume that  $D^{(n)}(Z) = 0$ for $n>2$. **This seems to be the condition that describes a Markov process $X_t$ as a diffusion process** (since a diffusion process is a continuous Markov process whose distribution over time satisfies the Fokker-Planck).

What does it mean for $D^{(n)}(Z) = 0$ for $n>2$? I'm guessing it's some kind of regularity condition that prevents a large jump in a small time interval, but I don't understand how to interpret the equation.

Comment: I don't have the time to go through the details in your cited reference, but whatever they are doing there, most definitely I wouldn't call it "the usual derivation" of the FP-equation.

Comment: @Tobsn Interesting, I'll look for another one. I saw this method in two separate lecture notes so I assumed it was standard.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the notes I mentioned in an earlier question of yours contain a better exposition on that topic.

Comment: This may not help, but if you are familiar with the idea of a martingale problem and the generator of a Markov process, the general form of the Kolmogorov forward equation (of which the F-P equation is a special case) is a fairly quick consequence of that characterization of the Markov property. Here are some slide lecture notes: http://www.math.wisc.edu/~kurtz/Lectures/NELDLECT.pdf With that in mind, an interpretation of your question might be "why doesn't the third derivative appear in the generator of Markov processes?" The answer to that is Markov generators satisfy the maximum principle.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Thanks for the references! I didn't know that Markov generators are dissipative, and I'm not sure how to interpret that... but I believe the criteria from my question should apply to diffusion processes and not Markov processes in general.

Comment: Oh, I realize you probably meant diffusion operators satisfy the maximum principle, which makes sense.

Comment: It's more general. If $\mathcal{L}$ is the generator of a Markov process, $P_t$ is the associated semigroup, and if $g \in \mathcal{D}(\mathcal{L})$ has a global maximum at $x$, then $P_t g(x) - g(x) \leq 0$ (since $x$ is a global maximum and $P_t g$ is an average). Divide by $t>0$ and send $t$ to 0 to obtain $\mathcal{L}g(x) \leq 0$. Anyway my intuition may just be wrong on the interpretation of that condition. I do not really think about any of this in terms of that kind of an expansion.